# abp.io Auto REST Service Controller Naming

Tags: abp

We are starting to migrate from Boilerplate to ABP.io. However, I am not sure how to define the naming convention that gets expose for AppServices.
For example,

```
public class DAFAppService : PlatformAppService
```

usually exposes the service as /api/daf

With abp.io, the service is exposed as /api/d-af
Is there a way to adjust the naming convention to match the original boilerplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to trace this down. The framework now uses Kebaberize, which separates the input words with hyphens and all words are converted to lowercase

The link below provides the way to adjust this. I used the line below to solve my issue.

```
opts.UseV3UrlStyle = true;
```

**Reference Site**
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5325